# COUNT() with nulls, inside subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have a bit of a problem with an advanced query that I am struggling to get my head around.

Essentally there are votes in a votes table that correspond to a given soundtrack. My query needs to get a rank for a soundtrack based on the votes that it has been awarded.

My approach below works just fine when there are votes in the table but the rank is given a `NULL` value when there are none in there.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT soundtrack.*, 
       (SELECT WrappedQuery.rank 
        FROM   (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, 
                       prequery.soundtrack_id 
                FROM   (SELECT @rownum := 0) sqlvars, 
                       (SELECT Count(*), 
                               soundtrack_id 
                        FROM   vote 
                        GROUP  BY vote.soundtrack_id 
                        ORDER  BY Count(*) DESC) prequery) WrappedQuery 
        WHERE  WrappedQuery.soundtrack_id = soundtrack.id) AS rank 
FROM   soundtrack 
WHERE  soundtrack.id = 33 
       AND live = 1 
ORDER  BY rank ASC
```

I have a feeling the problem is to do with the `(SELECT COUNT(*))` part, but everything I have tried so far isn't working out.

Hoping someone could shed some light on my issue.

**EDIT**
Here's the SQLFiddle
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8db2/2/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THAT ONE IS GOOD:

```
SELECT soundtrack.*, 
(SELECT WrappedQuery.rank 
FROM   (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, 
               prequery.soundtrack_id 
        FROM   (SELECT @rownum := 0) sqlvars, 
               (
               SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(vote.soundtrack_id),0) AS no_rows, 
                       soundtrack.id AS soundtrack_id 
                FROM   soundtrack
                LEFT JOIN  vote ON soundtrack.id=vote.soundtrack_id
                GROUP  BY soundtrack.id
                ORDER  BY 1 DESC
               ) prequery) WrappedQuery 
WHERE  WrappedQuery.soundtrack_id = soundtrack.id) AS rank 
FROM   soundtrack
ORDER  BY rank ASC;
```

SEE: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74698/2/0

Comment: Im afraid I was wrong, someone else was working on the data and voted, making the query work. Anyone else?

Comment: is taht solving Your problem ?

Comment: Thank you for your response but it still doesnt work when there are no votes.

Comment: If you remove a few of the votes from the insert in sqlfiddle you'll see what i mean

Comment: Now it's working - wrong grouping collumn in left join - so that was working only with ONE null   http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74698/1/0

Comment: That did it! Put that in your answer and I'll accept it! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: it's ok there. I am glad to be helping you

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck ranking in my own work using the row_number function. But otherwise, the coalesce function might help you out.

```
SELECT soundtrack.*, rankquery.rank
FROM (
    SELECT row_number() over(partition by prequery.soundtrack_id order by prequery.num_votes) as rank,
    prequery.soundtrack_id
        FROM (
            SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) as num_votes, soundtrack_id
            FROM vote
            GROUP BY soundtrack_id
            ORDER BY num_votes DESC
            ) prequery
    ) rankquery
INNER JOIN soundtrack
rankquery.soundtrack_id = soundtrack.id
WHERE  soundtrack.id = 33 
       AND live = 1
ORDER BY rank
```

Comment: Specifically: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by prequery.soundtrack_id order by prequery.num_votes) as rank,
    p' at line 4 `

Comment: My fault, MySQL doesn't recognize the row_number function. You are correct in using the variable. See additional post.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT soundtrack.*, rankquery.rank
FROM(
    SELECT prequery.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank 
            (
            SELECT COALESCE(Count(*),0) as num_votes, 
                   soundtrack_id 
            FROM   vote 
            GROUP BY soundtrack_id 
            ORDER BY num_votes DESC
            ) as prequery,
            (SELECT @rownum := 0) as sqlvars
    ) rankquery
INNER JOIN soundtrack
rankquery.soundtrack_id = soundtrack.id
WHERE  soundtrack.id = 33 
       AND soundtrack.live = 1
ORDER BY rankquery.rank ASC
```

Comment: There's a syntax error there and I cant really see where the issue is?

Comment: I just reworked the code a little bit to try and resolve the syntax error

Comment: Still a syntax error, here's the sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8db2/2/0

Comment: That is using the original SQL i posted, you can see the exact error there.